# how to set supported interface orientations in user-defined settings?

Tags: orientation, user-defined-functions, info.plist, buildconfiguration

I need to use User-defined settings to set the supported interface orientations for iPhone, depending on my build configuration.

In User-defined settings I have:

[image: user-defined]

In my info.plist I set:

[image]

But it doesn't work. The iPhone is launched in Portrait mode...
To be sure it comes from my custom settings, I run without User-defined variable in the .plist, and it works fine:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, I created 2 info.plist one for each build configurations instead, with the supported interface orientations associated:

- info-conf1.plist
- info-conf2.plist

Then in Build Settings > Packaging, set the correct plist.